# foreach loop through json values

Tags: php, json, foreach

I have a json result from an URL:

```
{
        "result": [{
            "user.name": "Spider Man",
            "user": "a4ac7bfe6f581640a62d3c31be3ee4dc"
        }, {
            "user.name": "Bat Man",
            "user": "af406b85e4b13500b95fa1eeac1ce626"
        }, {
            "user.name": "Iron Man",
            "user": "18ed9aba4ffb07006979ab6ba110c757"
        }, {
            "user.name": "Ant Man",
            "user": "877a503a98cc4200b95f526ea1ece471"
        }, {
            "user.name": "Captain America",
            "user": "8ec0d9634f2f22004b19ca1f0310c791"
        }]
    }
```

How to create a foreach loop to get the following output:

```
Spider Man
Bat Man
Iron Man
Ant Man
Captain America
```

And the same for the user-values in the json.

I tried following code but I can't figure it out:

```
$json = file_get_contents($queryURL, false, $context) or die ("keine verbindung");
$array = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($array as $data) {
    $data->user;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you pass true as a second parameter to `json_decode($json, true)`, this will convert it into an array, so you need to use something like `$data['elementName']`

Comment: You don't even need a loop for this, just do `echo implode('<br>', array_column($array, 'user.name'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You decoded as an array not an object.  Also, there is another level `result`:

```
foreach($array['result'] as $data) {
    echo $data['user'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. This worked for me ;-)